# Postgresql left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables `cars` and `usage`. I create a record in usage once a month for some of cars.
Now I want to get distinct list of cars with their latest usage that I saved.

first of all look at the tables please

```
cars:

| id | model       | reseller_id |
|----|-------------|-------------|
| 1  | Samand Sall | 324228      |
| 2  | Saba 141    | 92933       |
```

```
usages:

| id | car_id | year | month | gas |
|----|--------|------|-------|-----|
| 1  | 2      | 2020 | 2     | 68  |
| 2  | 2      | 2020 | 3     | 94  |
| 3  | 2      | 2020 | 4     | 33  |
| 4  | 2      | 2020 | 5     | 12  |
```

## The problem is here

- I need only the latest usage of year and month

I tried a lot of ways but none of them is good enough. because sometimes this query gets me one ofnot latest records of usages.

```
SELECT * FROM cars AS c
LEFT JOIN
     (select *
      from usages
     ) u on (c.id = u.car_id)
order by u.gas desc
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: The latest usage of each car for each year or for each month?

Comment: a list of cars (distinct) with their latest usage@zealous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a DISTINCT ON in the derived table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cars AS c
  LEFT JOIN (
    select distinct on (u.car_id) *
    from usages u
    order by u.car_id, u.year desc, u.month desc
  ) lu on c.id = lu.car_id
order by u.gas desc;
```

Comment: @a_horse_iwth_no_name . . . Is there any reason to use a subquery here, rather than doing the `join` and the `distinct on` without a subquery?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Mainly because this structure resembles the original query more closely. But I also found this to be faster quite frequently compared to applying the `distinct on ()` on the complete result

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I was wondering if the optimization worked better with a subquery.  Postgres does some pretty nifty things in the optimizer, but this may not be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need window function `row_number`. Here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jrbw7rBCd23BGBfDBe8UaR/2).

```
select
  id,
  model,
  reseller_id
from
(
  select
    c.id,
    model,
    reseller_id,
    row_number() over (partition by u.car_id order by u.id desc) as rn
  from cars c
  left join usages u
  on c.id = u.car_id
) subq
where rn = 1
```

Comment: the latest record is always having bigger id in usage per each vps

Comment: @Omid try now. I have updated the answer. provided the demo as well.

Comment: It's postgresql and a syntax error has been occoured

Comment: @Omid demo is in `postgres` and it is working. did you check that?

Comment: Yeah I checked it. but it says `syntax error at or near (` that is right after `row_number`

Comment: @Omid demo is working for me perfectly, did you run it and check the result you are getting?